# How to stop using Hindi number in Arabic translation of products

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

When using English version of website, price is shown in Arabic number (common one). But when using Arabic version of website, price is shown in Hindi number.

I don't want price to be shown in Hindi Numbers.

English view of products (Arabic Numbers)

[image]

Arabic view of products (Hindi Numbers)

[image]
How to force using Arabic Numbers in both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the NumberFormatDefinitionEvent ("commerce_price.number_format") and change $definition['numbering_system'] to 'latn' for your locale.

Comment: Seems to be the solution, but I couldn't figure out how to do that, do I have to implement a hook in my custom module or theme.

Comment: You'll have to learn about event subscribers in general. Yes, they are implemented in modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think your theme use this font, you must change font used in price, for test, use inspect element in chrome browser and change font and see result.

Comment: no, it's not in the theme. the characters translated in commerceguys/intl library.